# Override right arrow firefox with code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, jquery-plugins, browser

I want to use [keystrokes](http://boedesign.com/blog/2009/12/30/keystrokes-for-jquery/) , in my website. But the problem is, when you press the right arrowkey in firefox the page jumps a little bit to the right. I don't want that. This is my code:

```
 $(document).bind('keystrokes', {
                            keys: ['arrow right']               
                       }, function(event){
                            goRight();  
                            event.preventDefault();
                            // and / or
                            event.stopPropagation();

                            return false;
                       });
```

But this doesn't work. Am I able to override the firefox settings to go to the right when the right arrowkey is pressed? IE doesn't has this, so it works perfectly there. Or is it a browser issue, and there is no solution to this (except making my page small enough for the window).

I should say that my page is wider than the screen, and the body has `overflow:hidden;`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess: add `event.preventDefault()` along with return false.

Edit: nope that won't work, and I don't know about keystrokes, but this will work:

```
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
 if (event.keyCode == 39) {
     event.preventDefault();
     return false;
 }
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work, but thanks for youre effort! Or did I place it wrong (see question, ive eddited it)

Comment: You're right, that won't work - I don't know how to do it with keystrokes, see my edited answer for how to without though.

Comment: haha I don't care about the keystrokes! I'm even happy that you can do it without xD Thank you very much! This works perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use :

```
event.preventDefault();
// and / or
event.stopPropagation();
```

?

Comment: No I haven't, but it doesn't work either. Thanks for the effort. Or did I place it wrong? I've eddited the question, that's the way it looks right now, and it regrettably doesn't work.